# Issue with jackson deserializing, sets all variables to null

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying, and failing to deserialize in jackson 2.9.2, i am trying to make a game, for a uni project, where i am working on a save function, where i can save my Player class, and serialize it, but when i try to deserialize it, and make a new player from it, it sets all the variables to null, this is my method:

```
public void LoadSaveString() throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    //module.addDeserializer(SaveFile.class, new SaveDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    String filePath = "files/SaveFile.json";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)); 
    testfile = reader.readLine();

    System.out.println("Stringen testfilen bliver printet: " + testfile);
    Player player1 = (Player) mapper.readValue(testfile, Player.class);
    System.out.println("Test 2: " + player1.toString());

}
```

and the output i get is:

> Stringen testfilen bliver printet: {"player":{"hp":100,"air":97,"inventory":[],"hasCalledHelp":false,"wonGame":false,"playerName":"Mads","awesomePoints":0,"totalTimePlayed":3,"terminateThreads":false,"stopThreadOxygen":false,"stopThreadHP":false,"name":"Mads"}}
>
> Test 2: Player{hp=0, air=0, inventory=null, hasCalledHelp=false, wonGame=false, awesomePoints=0, totalTimePlayed=0, terminateThreads=false, stopThreadOxygen=false, stopThreadHP=false}

And i have set my player class to ignore unknown properties, so i only, get and set, the things that are important for the playerclass

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

and the properties in my Player class:

```
public class Player {
private int hp;
private int air;
private ArrayList<Item> inventory;
private boolean hasCalledHelp = false;
private boolean wonGame = false;
public String playerName = "Mads"; // Non-negotiable
public int awesomePoints = 0;
public int totalTimePlayed = 0;
```

Edit:

The content in the file SaveFile.json:

```
{
    "player": {
        "hp": 100,
        "air": 97,
        "inventory": [],
        "hasCalledHelp": false,
        "wonGame": false,
        "playerName": "Mads",
        "awesomePoints": 0,
        "totalTimePlayed": 3,
        "terminateThreads": false,
        "stopThreadOxygen": false,
        "stopThreadHP": false,
        "name": "Mads"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest that you don't just read the first line but the whole file to a string. Just to make sure that JSON files with another format are supported.
Also, as Tobias already stated, the JSON file is not a "Player" it just contains a Player. Alternatively to Tobias' approach you can also pick the Player part in the JSON file.

```
public void LoadSaveString() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    String filePath = "files/SaveFile.json";

    //Read the whole file and not just one line
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
    String testfile = new String(encoded, "utf-8");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(testfile);
    //Pick only the player part
    String playerPart = json.getJSONObject("player").toString();

    System.out.println("Stringen testfilen bliver printet: " + testfile);
    Player player1 = (Player) mapper.readValue(playerPart, Player.class);
    System.out.println("Test 2: " + player1.toString());

}
```

Also the Player class needs getters and setters for each attribute:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Player {
    private int hp;
    private int air;
    private boolean hasCalledHelp = false;
    private boolean wonGame = false;
    public String playerName = "Mads"; // Non-negotiable
    public int awesomePoints = 0;
    public int totalTimePlayed = 0;

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }
    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }
    public int getAir() {
        return air;
    }
    public void setAir(int air) {
        this.air = air;
    }
    public boolean isHasCalledHelp() {
        return hasCalledHelp;
    }
    public void setHasCalledHelp(boolean hasCalledHelp) {
        this.hasCalledHelp = hasCalledHelp;
    }
    public boolean isWonGame() {
        return wonGame;
    }
    public void setWonGame(boolean wonGame) {
        this.wonGame = wonGame;
    }
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }
    public int getAwesomePoints() {
        return awesomePoints;
    }
    public void setAwesomePoints(int awesomePoints) {
        this.awesomePoints = awesomePoints;
    }
    public int getTotalTimePlayed() {
        return totalTimePlayed;
    }
    public void setTotalTimePlayed(int totalTimePlayed) {
        this.totalTimePlayed = totalTimePlayed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON of your file is an `Object` that has an attribute `player`. It's not a `Player`

```
{
    "player": { "hp":100, ... }
}
```

Something like:

```
public class PlayerWrapper {
    public player Player;
}
```

The JSON should be

```
{
    "hp":100,
    "air":97,
    "inventory":[],
    "hasCalledHelp":false,
    "wonGame":false,
    "playerName":"Mads",
    "awesomePoints":0,
    "totalTimePlayed":3,
    "terminateThreads":false,
    "stopThreadOxygen":false,
    "stopThreadHP":false,
    "name":"Mads"
}
```

or if you can not change the file use the `PlayerWrapper`:

```
mapper.readValue(testfile, PlayerWrapper.class)
```